# Replace Viner Settanta seat post securing wedge

Tags: frames

My seat post wedge has been removed. There seems to be loads of different styles and shapes depending on the make and model of frame. Does anybody know if any other makes will fit it as having trouble sourcing one. Planet x may have some in a month but that means the bike is out of action for ages

Comment: Looks like a proprietary component. Did you contact Viner?

Comment: If this is the bit straight under the saddle then good luck - so many types and styles and they're not often sold as spares.  In the interests of timeliness, you might need to replace the whole seatpost, to keep the bike usable.

Comment: @criggie feel like you're referring to the saddle clamp, OP is asking about the newfangled part that holds the seatpost in place hidden in the seat tube area. still, answer might still be "good luck"!

Comment: @Swifty Oh so its functionally the seatpost clamp in the frame?  Yep time to talk to the frame maker.  And once OP gets a replacement, take steps to not lose it... perhaps wire or cable-tie it in place.

Comment: I have a spare saddle clamp wedge for viner Settanta I can sell. Email eeraks@yahoo.com

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=seat+post+wedge&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ4JTYzpfmAhVCqJ4KHdadB-UQ_AUoAnoECA4QBA&biw=1118&bih=554